# NavigationBar Logo blurred in iOS 13 devices

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have an app logo in the Navigation bar title view. It was showing fine before. But when I'm using the app in iOS 13 devices (iPhone 11, iPhone X), the app logo is blurry. Image size is **225*75**

Here is the sample image,

[image: sample logo]

I'm using navigationItem titleView:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

Also, tried navigationBarAppearance as well.

```
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.backgroundColor = CustomColor.COLOR_PRIMARY
            //appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: CustomColor.COLOR_ACCENT]
            let bar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
            bar?.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            bar?.standardAppearance = appearance
            bar?.compactAppearance = appearance
        }
```

But it's not working. Can you help me to fix that?

Comment: did u tried .pdf asset

Comment: @AbdulKarim: Yeah. Tried that too.. But didn't work.

Comment: can u share ViewController code in git, to have a look